# Partial index for query with "limit"

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a query which has limit(25) (with sort) on a collection with 10 Million+ documents. Is there an efficient way for MongoDB to have only top 25 entries so it saves space ? Like partial indexes where it only has top 25 documents ?

Reviewing partial indexes, dont find a way to specify this.

Comment: Nope. A potential workaround here would be to create and maintain a 'materialized view' of that top data, but it's unclear if that would be worth the trouble. Alternatively you might have some field that helps distinguish the newer documents from the older ones, periodically updating it when they become 'old'. You could create a partial index using that field as the filter to achieve some space savings, though you'd have to remember to include that field in your query (to make the index eligible for use) etc